# Pivot does not allow subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, pivot

I have the following table with conditions

[image]

I have to make a pivot that looks like this

[image]

I wanted to make a subselect in the pivot and it wouldn't let me. each value has its condition

Comment: This sounds like a "Dynamic Pivot" which is usually difficult to pull of in an RDBMS, although it may depend on what RDBMS you are using. Can you update the tags on this question with your RDBMS (postgres, sql server, mysql, oracle, snowflake, teradata, azure, etc).

Comment: are you working with mysql or oracle?

Comment: Sql server ....

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: "I wanted to make a subselect in the pivot and it wouldn't let me." - it sounds like you tried something. Can you show what you attempted? It might spark some recognition in would-be question answerers.

Answer (score 0):

We `unpivot` `aux`, `cro`, and `pep` and then pivot them back with `sum`.

```
select value
      ,"20/01/2020"
      ,"21/01/2020"
from   (
       select value, DATE, CNT from   t
       unpivot("CNT" for "BIT" in (AUX, CRO, PEP)) up
       ) up
pivot  (sum(cnt) for DATE in ("20/01/2020", "21/01/2020")) p
```

| value | 20/01/2020 | 21/01/2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dHaDKG6D)